# Zend redirect() is not working with AJAX request?

Tags: php, zend-framework, redirect

For example I have an action in Controller.

```
public function redirectnowAction() {
   $this->_redirect( '/module/controller/action' );
}
```

When I call above action in normal way then it redirect successfully to desired location But when I call above action by AJAX then it does not redirect to required URL and only show desired page content in firebug.

**JS code for AJAX**

```
jQuery('.AjaxLink').live( 'click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // load the href attribute of the link that was clicked
    jQuery.getJSON(this.href, function(snippets) {
        for(var id in snippets) {
            // updated to deal with any type of HTML
            jQuery('#' + id).html( snippets[id] );
        }
    });
});
```

How to redirect to action after AJAX request ?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to manage a redirect request after a JQuery Ajax call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199099/how-to-manage-a-redirect-request-after-a-jquery-ajax-call)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do it directly, here's what I'd do. In the action called via AJAX, include something like this:

```
echo Zend_Json::encode(array('redirect' => '/module/controller/action'));
```

This way, your AJAX call will receive a JSON object as a response. In jQuery's `$.ajax()` call, you can specify a `success` event, e.g.:

```
'dataType': 'json', // expects to receive a JSON-formatted response
'success': function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    window.location.replace('http://www.example.com' + data.redirect);
}
```

Comment: OK.. What if I return `echo Zend_Json::encode(array('jsredirect' => 'window.location.replace("/module/controller/action")'));` from action. And in success method we check if json key starts from `js`, If it is starting with string `js` then treat it as javscript code and `eval` it.

Comment: I've never done it in such a way, but I guess `eval`ing the returned string as JS code would work as well.

Answer (score 5):

When you use a redirect, you send a header to the user's browser to fetch content at the new location.

AJAX requests are not usually setup to handle such redirects. They simply initiate a request, and return the response.

The best-case solution is to reorganize your code so a redirect is not necessary. If you cannot eliminate the redirect, you must update your Javascript to recognize the redirect status (HTTP 301, for example) and initiate a new request.

Comment: You mean I have to redirect with javascript instead of zend redirect method ??

Comment: In Javascript, you can read the response from the PHP server which says "Redirect to '/module/controller/action'", and initiate a new AJAX request to that location.

Answer (score 1):

The ajax request itself would be subject to the redirect, not the browser window. Hence you would see the redirected content as the data returned via ajax. One solution would be to do a javascript redirect once the ajax request has been successfully run.